# azure functions throw System.OperationCanceledException

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

My project is using Azure function send data to AWS SNS. However there is a Exception throw out roughly 1 per day. We process 400,000 data per day. Does this means the function running more than 5 mins and azure function canceled this thread or there is another reason? We monitor Azure function using application insight.

```
"System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException".
```

Error log:

```
System.OperationCanceledException:
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.NamespaceManagerExtensions+<CreateSubscriptionIfNotExistsAsync>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusSubscriptionListenerFactory+<CreateAsync>d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexer+ListenerFactory+<CreateAsync>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.HostListenerFactory+<CreateAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener+<StartAsyncCore>d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ShutdownListener+<StartAsync>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost+<StartAsyncCore>d__25.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHostManager.RunAndBlock (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-script\src\WebJobs.Script\Host\ScriptHostManager.cs: 184)
```

Comment: Do you have any more of a stack trace to go with that? 'Cause that kind of exception could be coming from anywhere.

Comment: Function timeouts should give you a FunctionTimeoutException (https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/3696dd28df66996b1adcc0697f0d0f88f865cb64/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/FunctionTimeoutException.cs ) . 
You really need the callstack for more context.  For example, maybe your function is calling an texternal service (AWS) and that service times out 1 in 400,000 times.

Comment: I'm getting the same OperationCanceledException in my C# service. It's being handled internally (not bubbling up to my code) but I notice it in my debug window as well as red marker events in the diagnostic tool window, while running in the debugger. They occur quite frequently for me, possibly one per messgae.

Comment: I have seen the ServiceBusTrigger that is supposed to automatically Complete messages from Service Bus Queue when the Function finishes executing end up throwing the OperationCanceledException. And, it does it in a way that isn't catchable by your code since it's in Azure Functions... seems like a bug somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

No. If the function execution was taking longer than 5 mins, you would get a  `FunctionTimeoutException`.  Azure functions on the consumption plan can be extended to run 10 mins if needed.

This type of error - `System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException` - typically means that a service you were calling in code was taking longer than a defined timeout period.  The timeout elapsed, and the thread was killed.

Most likely you are using the [AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SNS/TSNSClient.html) library to communicate to AWS SNS?  Here is the aws sdk .net team [discussing](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/67) this exact type of error bubbling up from their library.

So, the error you are seeing is probably coming from their code.  SNS timed out.  It's up to that library to handle it gracefully.